# How to load huge data from the server ,storing it in local database and displaying in UItableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, afnetworking

I am downloading huge data using `AFnetworking` and storing into the local database and displaying in the tableview, When i download less data , table loads soon but when i download huge data and store its getting stuck for sometime because all operations are on main thread.

Can somebody tell me how to do this all process on background , so that user can use the App without any problem .

**Code:**

```
-(void) AddRecentCallLogs:(NSDictionary *)args :(NSString * ) type{

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{


    if([type isEqualToString:@"dailed"])
    {
        NSString *phoneNumber=[args objectForKey:@"destination_number"];;
        NSString *date=[args objectForKey:@"added_date_time"];
        NSString *name=[self getName:phoneNumber];

        if(name==NULL)
        {
            name=@"NOT_FOUND";
        }
       appDelegate=(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

        [appDelegate SetPhoneLogs:name :phoneNumber :date :@"Dailed"];
        [self.tableView reloadData];

    }
    else
    {
        NSString *phoneNumber=[args objectForKey:@"source_number"];;
        NSString *date=[args objectForKey:@"added_date_time"];
        NSString *name=[self getName:phoneNumber];

        if(name==NULL)
        {
            name=@"NOT_FOUND";
        }
        appDelegate=(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

        [appDelegate SetPhoneLogs:name :phoneNumber :date :@"Received"];

        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }

    });
}
```

In other function I am calling above method:

```
  AFJSONRequestOperation *operation1 = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request1 success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {

        resp = [JSON objectForKey:@"result"];
        //NSLog(@"%@-- %@",JSON,resp);

        self.recent_calllogs = [JSON objectForKey:@"log"];

        if(recent_calllogs.count<=0)
            [SVProgressHUD dismiss];

        for(NSDictionary *info in recent_calllogs)
        {
            [self AddRecentCallLogs:info :@"received"];
        }

        NSString *last_record=[JSON objectForKey:@"lastid"];

        if(last_record!=NULL)
        {
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
             setObject:last_record forKey:@"recent-R"];

//            NSString *savedValue = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]stringForKey:@"recent-R"];


            //NSLog(@"saved:%@",savedValue);
        }



    } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
        NSLog(@"Request Failed with Error: %@, %@", error, error.userInfo);


    }];
```

Comment: I tried to do the loading in separate thread but still the same problem, Can you please tell me where exactly i need to start in separate thread ? or is there something please ?

Comment: Can you show your codes first ?

Comment: Please see the above code

Answer (score -1, accepted):

implement paginator on server, and on device Pull-to-refresh, take a look at https://github.com/instructure/CKRefreshControl

loading large data at once it's too time consuming, 2 reasons for that :

- downloading data and parsing it
- saving it to database (for my experience 8MB of json text (30k objects) is saving for about 30-50 secs )
- (optional) if you are using dynamic height for table row in table view, it is also very time consuming  , because system calls method for calculating height for every row BEFORE rendering the table.